# install firefox in ubuntu-server edition

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, firefox

I have ubuntu server edition installed and I want to install firefox inside it , I don't want full ubuntu-desktop package just a minimal setup which would let me run firefox inside ubuntu-server 10.04 LTS

Comment: Only with a headless X server.

Comment: Do you really need firefox and a gui? Otherwise you could use `lynx`.

Comment: yes I do and I am looking for a minimum required environment for similar system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to install Firefox and run it remotely, install the [`firefox`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/firefox) package. If you also want to run Firefox locally, you'll need a GUI environment: install the [`x-window-system`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/x-window-system) package. If you also want to run Firefox locally comfortably, you'll need a window manager (any of the packages that provide the `x-window-manager` virtual package) or desktop environment (the Ubuntu default is Gnome, install at least [`gnome-core`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-core)).

I assume you only have a command line at your disposal; use the [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-get.8.html) command to manipulate packages, or [`aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/aptitude.8.html) for a command line or text mode interactive program.

```
apt-get install firefox x-window-system gnome-core
```

Strictly speaking, this won't be a minimal system, as it'll pull up a few packages that are recommended but not strictly necessary. Install all recommended packages unless you understand why you don't need them (in other words, if you need to ask, install them all).